# Calculate sum of select fields in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a problem that it's been haunting me for a few days already, I have a dynamic select field where the user pick an ingredient from the DB and if he wants to add more ingredients he just click on  'Add' button and another select field is created, all select fields show its name and price(as text) and there's an input text field( basePrice) that should have the sum of every select created

**Select field**

```
   <select name="ingredienteId[]" id="ingredienteId"  onchange="DoMath()">
          <?php foreach($ingredientes as $ingrediente) {
       $essaEhATorta = $torta['ingredienteId'] == $ingrediente['id'];
        $selecao = $essaEhATorta ? "selected='selected'" : "";
        ?> 
            <option value="<?=$ingrediente['id']?>" <?=$selecao?>>
 <?=$ingrediente['nome']?> <?=$ingrediente['price']?>  
        </option>
                              <?php } ?> 
    </select>
```

**Dynamic select field**

```
$('#add').click(function() {
var newSelect = $('<label>Ingrediente</label> <select name="ingredienteId[]" id="ingredienteId" class="form-control"> <?php foreach($ingredientes as $ingrediente) {$essaEhATorta = $torta["ingredienteId"] == $ingrediente["id"];$selecao = $essaEhATorta ? 'selected="selected"' : "";?> <option value="<?=$ingrediente["id"]?>" <?=$selecao?>><?=$ingrediente["nome"]?><?=$ingrediente["preco"]?>   </option><?php } ?> </select>')
$('#notas').append(newSelect);
});
```

**basePrice input text field**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$torta['precoBase']?>" name="precoBase" id="basePrice"/>
```

As I said before, the select option has the name/price of the product as text,  `<?=$ingrediente['nome']?><?=$ingrediente['price']?>`, so as I only wanted the price I came up with this code:

**DoMath()**

```
function DoMath(){

var e = document.getElementById("ingredienteId");
var finalPrice= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
var noLetterPrice = finalPrice.replace(/[^0-9,"."]/g,'');
var result = parseFloat(noLetterPrice);
document.getElementById("basePrice").value = result;
```

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV4OI.jpg)

*Part of my code is in portuguese but I hope u guys understand*

As you can see the conversion part works but I have no idea how to make the sum part work, I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work

Comment: plz remove shorts tags first and not able to find #add in your html structure

Answer (score 2):

Instead of taking value and find price using regex will create issue when options names contains some digital values.

In Jquery  we can provide any custom attribute to any field.So take that price in one of custom attribute in option.It will be very easy.

Just try below code

**Select Field HTML Structure**

```
<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="0" name="precoBase" id="basePrice"/>
<div id="notas">
    <div id="ing_div">
        <label>Ingrediente</label> 
        <select name="ingredienteId[]" class="baseingredient">
            <option value="" ing-price="0"> Select Price</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($ingredientes as $ingrediente) {
                $essaEhATorta = false;
                $selecao = $essaEhATorta ? "selected='selected'" : "";

                ?> 
                <option value="<?= $ingrediente['id'] ?>" <?= $selecao ?> ing-price="<?= $ingrediente['price'] ?>">
                    <?= $ingrediente['nome'] ?> <?= $ingrediente['price'] ?>  
                </option>
            <?php } ?> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above HTML i have taken Price in **ing-price** attribute.

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
   $(document).on("click",'#add',function() {
        var newSelect = $('#ing_div').clone();
        newSelect.find("select[name='ingredienteId[]'").val();
        $('#notas').append(newSelect);
    });

    $(document).on("click",".baseingredient",function(){
        tot=0;
        $(".baseingredient").each(function(){
            tot+=parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").attr("ing-price"));

        })
        $("#basePrice").val(tot);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hey man great code, but the sum part is still not working here
the custom attribute really makes sense way better than regex, but I had to change ` $essaEhATorta = false;` to my old `$essaEhATorta = $torta['ingredienteId'] == $ingrediente['id'];` since that's how I join the ingredientsId with another table, I've tried `var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('ing-price');
            tot+=parseFloat(option);` but it's giving NaN on basePrice input
any hints?

Comment: Hey i just got it now, the parseFloat was passing NaN and idk why, I tried parseInt and it worked lol

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on()` instead of `.click()` and `onchange`, like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#add',function(){
    var newSelect = $('<label>Ingrediente</label> <select name="ingredienteId[]" id="ingredienteId" class="form-control"> <?php foreach($ingredientes as $ingrediente) {$essaEhATorta = $torta["ingredienteId"] == $ingrediente["id"];$selecao = $essaEhATorta ? 'selected="selected"' : "";?> <option value="<?=$ingrediente["id"]?>" <?=$selecao?>><?=$ingrediente["nome"]?><?=$ingrediente["preco"]?>   </option><?php } ?> </select>')
    $('#notas').append(newSelect);
});

$(document).on('change','#ingredienteId',function(){
    // calculate sum of every select fields
});
```

The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

From the [documentation of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) inside your script, which totals the cost of ingredients, when a select field has been changed.

We have to assign first `class` tag for your `select` inputs.

```
<select class="ing" .....
```

Have it also to the "to be appended" `select` inputs.

```
var newSelect = $('<label>Ingrediente</label> <select class="ing" .....
```

Using `each()`, we can run through all the `select` fields that has `class` tag of `ing`:

```
$(document).on("change", ".ing", function(){ /* WHEN A SELECT FIELD HAS CHANGED */

  var total = 0;
  $('.ing').each(function() { /* RUN ALL SELECT FIELD */
    total = total + parseInt($(this).val()); /* SUM UP ALL */
  });
  $("#basePrice").val(total); /* CHANGE THE VALUE OF BASE PRICE FIELD */

});
```

I prefer having

```
$(document).on("change", ".ing", function(){
```

rather than your previous

```
function DoMath(){
```

function due to the dynamically appended `select` fields.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/t6ujjqdw/3/) (example) that you can look up to.